# What is the difference between a variable and a parameter?

Tags: java, variables, parameters

Its a conceptual question. But I would like to use the right term at the right place. That is why I would like to read some other views on this.

Comment: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important "see: 'Why is research important?'")**. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/what-is-the-difference-in-meaning-between-a-variable-and-a-parameter-in-a-gi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In layman's words:**

- Imagine a function as a black box.
- You don't know how the black box works
- You only know what the black box does, but not how
- The black box needs something to work on, that you must provide
- The black box gives you something in return
- That thing you provide the black box is a parameter
- The pieces of information you don't know of, that the black box uses to do it's work, are variables
- But hey!, for you (the caller), the thing you give the black box can be a variable of your own, that you use to do your own work.
- You can also give the black box a literal, i.e, instead of passing it the variable `personName` you could pass it "Peter". The black box doesn't know whether you passed it a variable or a literal. Once inside the black box, it's a variable as seen from the perspective of the black box.
- Finally the black box gives you something back, which is called a "return value", which you can put in a variable or your own, or not, or you can pass to another box as a parameter.
- Some black boxes don't need you to pass them anything.
- Some black boxes don't return anything, and people call them "methods".
- Some people call parameters "arguments".

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are variables that only exist within a method, and are initialized automatically with the values passed to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters can be used as a special type of variable, but the basic difference is *scope*: that a variable is local (it only exists within the current method), whereas a parameter is external: it is passed in to the method from the caller.  This means that, if the parameter is passed by reference (including essentially any object type), changes to the parameter will be reflected in the calling code once the method exits, whereas anything done to a local variable does not live beyond the method. (Unless it gets passed elsewhere and stored, of course.)

Comment: Parameters are *never* passed by reference in Java. Java is *always* pass-by-value. Changes to the parameter will *not* be reflected outside the method. (Changes to the *argument* which is *referenced* by the parameter will, but that's a totally different matter. Java is not a purely functional language, it has shared mutable state.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag: When all objects are reference types anyway, that's hair-splitting at best.

Comment: Pass-by-reference vs. pass-by-value refers to *how* arguments are being passed, not *what* those arguments are. That is completely and utterly irrelevant. C is pass-by-value, no matter whether the argument being passed is an `int` or a pointer to some struct. Java is pass-by-value, no matter whether the argument being passed is an `int` or a reference to some object. If you can do this: `void foo(String bar) { bar = "World"; } void main(String... args) { String baz = "Hello"; foo(baz); assertTrue("World".equals(baz)) }` then it is pass-by-reference, otherwise it is pass-by-value.